# ValueError while Merging Lists in Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, numpy, merge

I'm trying to get one array out of several arrays in python 2.7

I found on the internet that this is done simply by adding both lists:

```
lista = [1,2,3]
listb = [3,4,5]
listc = lista + listb
```

In my case my first list i empty and the next list has 99 elements.

My code looks like this

```
data_complete = []
for i in range(1, numberOfFiles+1):
    data = getDataFromFile(i)
    data_complete = data_complete + data
```

The last line of code does not work, it returns the error:

```
data_complete = data_complete + data
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0) (99)
```

I would be glad if someone can solve this.

Kind Regards

Comment: I would guess that `data = getDataFromFile(i)` is what doesn't work as expected. can you verify what is returnwd by the function?

Comment: the variable data looks like this if i print it:

[ 0.001  0.002  0.003  ...  0.098  0.099]

Comment: @Thorsten The data returned is without comma?

Comment: is numpy somehow involved? this doesn't look like standard array representation?

Comment: You're using `numpy` then... Where is that part in the code?

Comment: yes the data is extracted from a numpy array, in the data variable it has no commas, as soon as i copy it to the list it has commas

Comment: your code does not show the part of copying to the list so you concatenate an array and numpy array. See lvc's answer.

Comment: This is correct, I didn't know that there is a difference in concatenating arrays and numpy arrays. This is why I selected the wrong part of the code. Now it works anyway, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `append` method if its a single item

```
data_complete.append (data)
```

You can use `extend` method if `data` itself is a list

```
data_complete.extend (data)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like `getDataFromFile` is returning a numpy array, rather than a list. In this case, `+` will use the *array's* concatenation routine, which has some extra requirements compared to `list`s (and returns another array). You can use the list `extend` method instead to get around this:

```
data_complete = []
for i in range(1, numberOfFiles+1):
    data = getDataFromFile(i)
    data_complete.extend(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

just `append` the data to your list

for example:

```
evens = []
for i in xrange(10):
    if i%2 == 0:
        evens.append(i)
```

at the end of this program `evens` will equal `[2,4,6,8]`

Comment: no this does not get me what i want, if i use append i got a list of lists, but i want one lists with all elements in it.

Comment: ohh i would use extend to add the lists instead of making each list go into another list!